# useを配列にした場合のloaderの読み込み順

Tags: webpack

webpackの設定をしているのですが、
loaderを配列で指定した場合、読み込む順番は、index番号が若い順で読み込まれるのでしょうか？

```js
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader'] // vue-style-loaderが読み込まれてからcss-loaderが読み込まれる？
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

複数のloaderを適用する場合、**右から左に適用されます**。

この場合、cssファイルにまず`css-loader`が適用され、次に`vue-style-loader`が適用されます。

[webpackのドキュメント](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleuse)に記載があります。

> Loaders can be chained by passing multiple loaders, which will be applied from right to left (last to first configured).

推測ですが、`require`でインラインにloaderを指定する記法（`require('vue-style-loader!css-loader!./app.css')`）の場合は右から左に適用されると理解するのが自然なので、それに合わせているのではないかと思います。

Comment: webpackのドキュメントに記載されていたんですね。
しっかりドキュメント読むようにします！

わかりやすい回答ありがとうございました！